# How to visualize FFT of a signal in Julia?

Tags: julia, fft, fftw

I'm trying to visualize a signal and its frequency spectrum in Julia.

I found the [FFTW](https://github.com/JuliaMath/FFTW.jl) package that provides the FFT and [DSP](https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl) for the frequencies.

Here is what I'm trying, with a sinusoidal signal:

```
using Plots
using FFTW
using DSP

# Number of points
N = 2^14 - 1
# Sample rate
fs = 1 / (1.1 * N)
# Start time
t0 = 0
tmax = t0 + N * fs

# time coordinate
t = [t0:fs:tmax;]

# signal
signal = sin.(2π * 60 * t)  # sin (2π f t)

# Fourier Transform of it
F = fft(signal)
freqs = fftfreq(length(t), fs)
freqs = fftshift(freqs)

# plots
time_domain = plot(t, signal, title = "Signal")
freq_domain = plot(freqs, abs.(F), title = "Spectrum")
plot(time_domain, freq_domain, layout = 2)
savefig("Wave.pdf")
```

I expected to see a nice plot with a peak in the 60 Hz, but all I got was a weird result:

[image: Imgur]

I'm ignoring the negative frequencies for now.

How should I do that in Julia?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you call `fs` in your code is not your sampling rate but the inverse of it: the sampling period.

The function `fftfreq` takes the sampling *rate* as its second argument. Since what you give as the second argument is the sampling period, the frequencies returned by the function are incorrectly scaled by `(1/(Ts^2))`.

I renamed `fs` to `Ts` and changed the second argument to `fftfreq` to the sampling rate `1.0/Ts`. I think you also need to shift the result of `fft`.

```
# Number of points 
N = 2^14 - 1 
# Sample period
Ts = 1 / (1.1 * N) 
# Start time 
t0 = 0 
tmax = t0 + N * Ts
# time coordinate
t = t0:Ts:tmax

# signal 
signal = sin.(2π * 60 .* t) # sin (2π f t) 

# Fourier Transform of it 
F = fft(signal) |> fftshift
freqs = fftfreq(length(t), 1.0/Ts) |> fftshift

# plots 
time_domain = plot(t, signal, title = "Signal")
freq_domain = plot(freqs, abs.(F), title = "Spectrum", xlim=(-1000, +1000)) 
plot(time_domain, freq_domain, layout = 2)
savefig("Wave.pdf")
```